# SQL Union : Selecting id of file_up table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I have two tables **treeview_items** and **file_up**

**treeview_items**

[image: img1]

**file_up**

[image: img2]

And a query (not written by me)

```
SELECT *
FROM treeview_items
UNION
    SELECT id + (select max(id) from treeview_items), name, 
          path as text,dir_id as parent_id
    FROM file_up
```

Now How can I modify this query so that **id** from **file_up** table will also be listed in the query result? I have tried few things but still stuck!

Current output and expected output, here column name **id from file_up** is just for demonstration.

[image: img3]

Comment: can u show your expected output

Comment: SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. How are you planning to accomplish this?

Comment: expected output should also contain id of file_up table

Comment: Share the expected output.

Comment: Which is the common column between both the tables?

Comment: @RakeshMishra Do you have any FK reference between the table? Or any common column?

Comment: No, it does not have any FK. actually this database is not designed by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if i get exactly what you are saying but are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT *, WhateverID = NULL
FROM treeview_items
UNION
    SELECT id + (select max(id) from treeview_items), name, 
          path as text,dir_id as parent_id, WhateverID
    FROM file_up
```